# How to denote inside a text file a new line and simply print it?

Tags: python

I have a text file that I am reading line by line and assigning each to a variable but some lines I would like to be printed with a new line so I can format them a bit. The text file looks like this:

Projectinfo.txt

```
Greeting: Hello,

How are you?

Farewell: Goodbye
```

Code:

newlinetxt.py

```
txtfile = 'ProjectInfo.txt' #Open the txt file
with open(txtfile, encoding="utf8") as file:
    content = file.readlines()

line1 = content[0]
line2 = content[1]

start = 'Greeting: '
end = 'Farewell: '
a = line1
Hellomsg = (a[a.find(start)+len(start):a.rfind(end)])

start = 'Farewell: '
end = ''
b = line2
Byemsg = (b[b.find(start)+len(start):b.rfind(end)])

print(Hellomsg)
print(Byemsg)

Hello
you?
```

When I print this out, it only prints the first line for the first variable `'Hellomsg'`  and then the second line is assigned to the second variable `'Byemsg'` instead of its own variable `"Farewell"`

Without the break, it prints:

```
Hello, How are you?
Goodbye
```

But I want:

```
Hello,
How are you?
Goodbye
```

I have also tried using `"Hello, \n How are you?"` in the .txt file but it will print the string with \n and not actually create a new line.

Comment: Yes, write an actual line break in the file. Most text editors let you do this by pressing the "Enter" key.

Comment: Your question isn't very specific.  Where do you actually need to put the newline? "Wherever it needs to be" doesn't give us much to work off of

Comment: @mkrieger1 I edited the post for further clarification, writing an actual line break doesn't work and it prints what came before the line break. Then the next line prints to the next variable instead of the variable on its own line.

Comment: @Jeff The newline needs to go where I put \n in the text. I edited that line and made it more clear, I was asking if \n is the correct character to put in the .txt doc or is it something else that it needs if not \n?

Comment: What are you using to run the code? putting a \n in a string should print a new line

Comment: Yes \n works as a string inside PyCharm, I am taking a string from a .txt file. If I put \n in the .txt file it will literally print \n and not make a new line.

Comment: I tested my regex and it works for your \n question in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

Hellomsg = re.sub("\\\\n", '\n', a)
```

`\n` is an invisible character and the only way to type it into a text editor is the 'Enter' button. The reason for so many backslashes is that when python reads in the "\n" in your text file, it adds a backslash before the first backslash to denote that the backslash is *literal*. When searching it for it, you need to find 2 literal backslashes, which means that the two backslashes need a backslash each.

If your actual problem is more complicated than your toy, you'll need to adjust the `"\\\\n"` so that you don't replace a backslash 'n'-something with a newline.

Comment: In my actually project I have about 10 lines, the "Hellomsg" is the 7th line and adding the `Hellomsg = re.sub("\\\\n", '\n', a)` it prints: ('Hello \\n How are you?', 'first line in the text')         I added this like so: `Hellomsg = (j[j.find(start)+len(start):j.rfind(end)]), re.sub("\\\\n", '\n', a)`

Comment: What is j? You never defined that in your example.

if `a = 'first line in the text'`, there is no '\\n' string inside of it in the first place.